# Google game services using gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, google-play-games

Is there a way to add google game services in a simple way using gradle 0.5+ like how its possible with the support library or the google play services:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play Game Services is not a separate library from the Google Play Services library.  It seems that you are using a very old version of play-services through.  Try the newest version, which definitely has the Games API:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'`